# How to add icon to mat-icon-button and have it same size as button without icon

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I want to ask how to add mat-icon to button tag but keep button height same as before.
Button height is 40px and it should be 40px. But when I add mat-icon to button then button makes itself higher by few pixels. Is there any way to make it same height as right button and leave icon there? (40px) I would like to not change size of right button because it have height that I want. I want to make left button smaller.

[image: button]

Ive tried to make icon smaller but there is not change. :/

[image]

[EDIT] My code:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the mat-icon-button directive on your button?

Comment: Oh yes sorry I didnt post whole code. I just edited my answer and posted whole button tag there.

Comment: Try adding that directive yo your button (i.e. <button mat-icon-button>...</button>. Looks like you've got quite a lot of conditional styling going on though which makes this hard to replicate.